# Magento 1.9.3 index.php redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I am working on an E-Commerce website project which I created in localhost. It worked fine, until I moved it online.

Since I moved it online, I've had issues accessing the `admin` page and the `index.php`. I've managed to make the `admin` page work and can now access the backoffice without any issues, but my `index.php` still shows me an *"error: too many redirects1"* page.

***What's happening?***

- Main page of my website is stuck in a redirecting loop (chrome error message : *this url tried to redirect you too many times*)
- Everytime I reload the main page, the url switches between www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com (might be an htaccess issue?)

***What I've done to try and solve the problem:***

- I have checked everything in `core_config_data` table to make sure
  the right urls are written in `web/secure/base_url` and
  `web/unsecure/base_url`. They are.
- I have manually cleared the `var/cache` and `var/session` from my
  FTP.
- I have cleared all cookies / cache from Chrome / Firefox
- I have reuploaded the files and database multiple times, thinking it might be due to a corrupted file from the upload.
- I have tried to edit the `htaccess`, but it didn't change anything.

***What should I do now ?***

I feel like I've tried everything.

As it's my first time with magento, I'm sure it's some dumb thing I might not know about, but I've read nearly every single post about this kind of issues on this website and haven't found anything to resolve it.

So I'm asking you. I'm willing to try every single idea you throw at me, as I've been stuck on this issue for a while now ^^

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

Weird, It seems that You make everything right. Try to find and update all url settings in core_config_data: `select * from core_config_data where path like '%url%'`. 
You can try update `web/url/redirect_to_base` config to 0 (if you have 1).

Remember to clear cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I have just done that, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the urls when I look at the [results](http://imgur.com/Ob89Tb1). 
As you can see, I have also changed `web/url/redirect_to_base` to 0 (I had 1), cleared the cache, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have just tried typing the full "https://..." and it works, but the same with "http://..." (so the unsecured url) doesn't work for some reason. Would you happen to know why ?

Comment: Maybe you have wrong redirect rule in nginx/apache2? I mean redirect to force https connection something like https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx